# Unable to import "hashlib"

Tags: encryption, hash, sha1, hashlib, python-2.4

I tried this code:

```
import hashlib
encrypted = hashlib.sha1(string)
encrypted = encrypted.digest()
```

But I got an error that says "No Module Named hashlib". What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I guess the python version you used is too old, according to http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html hashlib is only available in python 2.5+

Comment: It seems worth noting that *even when this already-ancient question was asked*, Python 2.5 had already been out for almost 5 years, and 2.7 and 3.2 had both been released.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've probably got a python version < 2.5. Use the [`sha`](http://docs.python.org/library/sha.html) module instead.

Here's the differences:

```
>>> import sha
>>> s = sha.new()
>>> s.update('hello')
>>> s.digest()
'\xaa\xf4\xc6\x1d\xdc\xc5\xe8\xa2\xda\xbe\xde\x0f;H,\xd9\xae\xa9CM'
```

vs

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> hashlib.sha1('hello').digest()
'\xaa\xf4\xc6\x1d\xdc\xc5\xe8\xa2\xda\xbe\xde\x0f;H,\xd9\xae\xa9CM'
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, FWIW and for others ending up here, but for hashlib.md5():

```
import md5

m = md5.new()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

hashlib is a new module/library in python **2.5**
the server certainly run **python 2.4** or earlier

Answer (score 0):

On some python derivatives such as Jython, use the following:

```
import _hashlib
h =  _hashlib()
md5Res = h.openssl_md5("helloYou").hexdigest()
print(md5Res)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find such errors related to the modules no found is to verify their path. I am completely able to run the python facebook ads api code through  console but when I try this code through c# i got several path related errors.

Just below given statement before the import statements to give the path of "hashlib.py file".

---

import sys

### sys.path.append('C:\Python34\Lib')

It has resolved my problem.