# Ways to launch python script from C#

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I used the search engine. I couldn't find the thing I want,and i'm not that good in programming.I have a .py script that use **hashlib and M2Crypto**,and when i use **iron python to run the program from c#** it says that **no module named hashlib**. I couldn't find a way to import hashlib to c# or ironpython even tho i searched all the net, i tried the following code it doesn't seem to work too. Can you help please thanks.

```
   Process p = new Process(); // create process (i.e., the python program
   GetShortPathName(decdbpath, shortPath, shortPath.Capacity);
   GetShortPathName(db, shortPath2, shortPath2.Capacity);
   p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Python27\\python.exe";
   p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   p.StartInfo.Arguments = a+"\\pycode.py" + shortPath + " " + 
                           txt_entermail.Text + " >" + db;
   p.Start(); // start the process (the python program)
   p.WaitForExit();
   MessageBox.Show("Decryption Done");
```

finally i found the problem, the path to the py script contained a space i fixed the problem, but now python script is refusing to take the arguments ? thanks

```
string format = string.Format(shortPath + "\\pycode.py"+" "+shortPath2.ToString() + " " + txt_entermail.Text + " > " + shortPath3.ToString());
```

this is the result:

usage C:\Users\win7\Ziad\MOBILE~1\DBEXPL~1\WINDOW~1\bin\Debug\pycode.py argument1 argument2 > argument3

Comment: Is this thread helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779143/run-a-python-script-from-c-sharp

Comment: i saw it, it didn't help out :(

Comment: I noticed that p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; is not set to true. Have you tried?

Comment: yeah i did it didn't work out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that and tell me :

```
p.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", cmd, args);
     p.UseShellExecute = false;
     p.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     using(Process process = Process.Start(p))
     {
         using(StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
         {
             string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
             Console.Write(result);
         }
     }
```

Comment: and the result from the reader.readtoend(); is empty, its like its not reading the script idk

Comment: Are you sure, your py code works fine ? It's possible your error come from concatenation on p.Arguments ?

Comment: yeah when i launched standalone from windows it works normally

Comment: do you use path with white space on arguments ?

Comment: GetShortPathName() - gives you the short path i imported the kernel32.dll method, so i have no problem with the white spacing in the paths.

Comment: the format of the argument is pyscrpit.py Argument1(string) Argument2(String) > Argument3(String)

Comment: have you tried to format your agument like this sample p.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", cmd, args);

Comment: i found the problem! the python isn't taking the arguments right!, i tried to string.format and give it to the .argument and it still not working ? can you help please ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is in your python script, not in your c#. See [Unable to import "hashlib"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557760/unable-to-import-hashlib)

Comment: my python script is working fine, i tried to use it externally

Comment: OK, you might want to make sure hashlib is in the path. Here's an answer that speaks to that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371994/importing-external-module-in-ironpython

Comment: And another question directly relating to hashlib and ironpython here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855211/can-i-use-all-standard-python-libraries-with-ironpython-or